# Import library from specific branch via variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I want to load shared-library implicity, and not dynamically, in Jenkinsfile, but select specific branch from per variable for shared-library.
For testing purpose, I tried to insert variable in @library statement per properties variable. It works, if I write the branch name directly inside.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
properties([
    stringParam(name: 'BRANCH_NAME', defaultValue: 'master')
  ])
])

@Library("custom-shared-library@${params.BRANCH_NAME}")

import com.custom.test.utils.*

println("hello world!")
```

**Got following error message:**

```
WorkflowScript: @Library value ‘custom-shared-library@$params.BRANCH_NAME’ was not a constant; did you mean to use the ‘library’ step instead?

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:319)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is it possible to insert variable in `@library()` statement?

Comment: In declarative, a library would likely be imported prior to resolving pipeline input parameters.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the right answer, that is not possible to add variables in @library statement.

Comment: @MattSchuchard see my answer, it works like a charm with `libraries` directive in declarative pipeline

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the scripted pipeline see the docs at  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically

```
properties([parameters([string(name: 'LIB_VERSION', defaultValue: 'master')])])
library "my-shared-library@${params.LIB_VERSION}"
```

for the declarative pipeline use `libraries` directive like described here https://github.com/cloudbees/intro-to-declarative-pipeline/blob/master/Exercise-04.md

```
libraries {
  lib("my-shared-library@${params.LIB_VERSION}")
}
```

The `libraries` directive was added in the version `1.1` of the [pipeline model definition plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-11). But for some reason I don't see it in the pipeline syntax documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the option. But as I described in my question, I want to try to load the shared-library implicit to get full CLASSPATH in order to access directly the function from src/.

Comment: I've added a declarative pipeline syntax as well

Comment: Thanks for detailed examples. Marked your edit post as solution.

Comment: I'm confused, this still doesn't address the import problem?  Don't we need `@Library("...") to enable import?

Comment: @PeterKahn can you share a code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: So, I need to use this @Library('our-jenkins-library') import com.us.buildsystem.DevState so I can use DevState in my jenkinsfiles.  Now, the solution is obvious - refactor logic into the library so I don't need to do that, then I can pass the branch or tag as part of a GString in the library "foo@${bar}" style